# Installing json -v '1.8.6' gem, throws gcc error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gcc, rubygems, bundler

some one in my team just updated some gem in the gemfile because of which gem json is resolved to version '1.8.6'. Which is not being installed. The error it throws is following:

```
anas:~$ sudo gem install json -v '1.8.6'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-
1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171017-7274-1ea5ank.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-
1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-
1.8.86/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wdate-time’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-
strong’
Makefile:239: recipe for target 'generator.o' failed
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6 
for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-
linux/2.3.0/json-1.8.6/gem_make.out
```

My ruby is 2.3.1p112 and gcc version is 4.7.4. I have tried to find out which gcc version json -v `1.8.6` use but I did not find anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My gcc version is 4.8.5. And its working. So one solution could be gcc update. Try that.

Comment: Also post any other logs if available.

Comment: All the logs from sudo gem install json -v '1.8.6' are added. What do you mean by other logs.

Comment: I am unable to install 4.8.5 version of gcc

Answer (score 0):

As pr my undarstanding the solution is to install libgmp3-dev.

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```